# Slow transfer speed between two Windows 7 computers over local wifi?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have two PCs running Win7 sitting next to each other. They both have identical TP-Link WiFi PCI cards and are connected to an Enkom router which is in the same room as the computers (which claims to have 802.11g WiFi).

I've set file sharing between the computers (not Homegroup), set "Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encryption" in Advanced file sharing settings, disabled TCP autotuning and turned off Remote Differential Compression.

Regardless of the changes I made, I can't get the transfer rate between the computers to go above 350KBps either way (when a copy dialog is initially opened, it starts at 512KBps but that immediately drops below 400KBps).

Is there anything else I can try doing? My Internet download speeds are literally faster (over Wifi) so this makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not even getting half the speed the user is getting in the link you shared...

Comment: There are just way too many factors to know why it's slow; computers, NICs, router/wifi settings, radio interference, etc. If all components are in the same room, why not connect cables and be done?

Comment: Because the router is in an awkward place to connect the computers via cable. Besides, that's not the point, I'm sure someone else will have a similar problem and won't be able to use cable in their case.

Comment: Take the router out of the picture; Setup an Ad Hoc WiFi network between the two PCs - is it any faster?

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Local data has to go over the WiFi twice (once to the AP, once from the AP) while Internet data only has to go over the WiFi once. So your maximum local WiFi-to-WiFi speed should be around half or your maximum Internet-to-WiFi speed.